# If I have that all groups $\mid G \mid < 100 \ncong A_5$ are not simple, does this imply solvable?

Tags: group-theory

If I have that all non-abelian groups $\mid G \mid < 100 \ncong A_5$ are not simple, does this imply that all groups $\mid G \mid < 100 \ncong A_5$ are solvable in a few steps? In other words, is there a condition for solvability for non-abelian groups that arises from a lack of simplicity-- perhaps not containing any simple groups?

Comment: Cyclic groups of prime order less than 100 are simple.

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: Well, it happens to be that is the situation but I don't think that "this" implies it.

Comment: Is there a condition for solvability for non-abelian groups that arises from a lack of simplicity-- perhaps not containing any simple groups?

Comment: @Timbuc Do these non-simple non-solvable groups necessarily contain simple groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If $|G|<100$ consider a composition series for $G$. Since its factors are simple, they all have to be either $A_5$ or abelian. If they're all abelian, $G$ is solvable, as desired. If, on the other hand, one of the composition factors is $A_5$, then its order, 60, divides the order of $G$, which means, since $|G|<100$, that $|G|=60$ and $G=A_5$.

Comment: What a slick proof. Thank you.